# Globals variable in class

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop

I am trying to put Globals variable in another variable of the class. But it is not working. Error log is show

> **syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE**.

```
class data{
    public $datav = $GLOBALS['dat'];

    public static function get(){
           return self::$datav;
    }

}
```

I also tried by replacing `self::$datav`; with `$this->datav`; but it is also giving same error.

I also want to know is there any way to use the variable which is outside the class. 
e.g:

```
$datav = array{'name'=>'assadf','asdf'=>'asddf'}
 class data{

        public static function get(){
               return $datav['name'];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using globals like that inside a class rather breaks the Encapsulation of a class.

Better to pass in values like that via a `__construct($var)`. But as you have a function defined as static I assume you want to make this class static so `__construct()` will not be called for a static class.

So you would have to create a setter method like so :-

```
class data{
    public $datav = NULL;

    public static function set($var) {
        $this->datav = $var;
    }

    public static function get(){
           return $this->$datav;
    }

}
```

Then call your class like

```
data::set($GLOBALS['dat']);

$localVar = data::get();
```

Comment: OP intends to hold `$GLOBALS` in their class, which is type `array`. I think `$datav` should be an `array` and `set` should have 2 parameters - `key` and `value`.

Comment: Quite irrelivant, its the use of globals in a class that is the BIG problem here.

Comment: Changed the `::set` to better suit the question

Answer (score -1):

Class properties must be assigned a constant value. Also the `$datav` has to be static in order to be accessed from the `get` method.

```
class data{
    public static $datav;

    public static function get(){
        if(!isset(self::$datav)) {
            self::$datav = $GLOBALS['dat'];
        }
        return self::$datav;
    }
}
```

For the second code, you can use the `global` keyword to tell PHP the variable you are using comes from the outer scope, not from the function scope:

```
$datav = array('name'=>'assadf','asdf'=>'asddf');
class data{
    public static function get(){
        global $datav;
        return $datav['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still using $GLOBALS inside the class, which is bad practice and breaks the encapsuation completely.

Comment: @RiggsFolly True, but there may be some cases where this would be the easiest solution. It's up to the questioner to decide which answer suits him more. I've fixed the syntactic problem, you've fixed the semantic problem. Both solutions can be helpful to other people, and you've already stated in your answer that encapsulation should not be broken.

Comment: `Easiest !== Correct` in almost all cases. Its not my role to insist, but also its not my role to lead people into Bad Practices. Who knows, its not outside the bounds of possibility that at some future date I may get engaged to fix/enhance this code. It would be nice if it didn't come with obvious rubbish in it.

Answer (score -2):

you should use `global` to let PHP know that's a global variable declared outside the class.

```
$datav = "something";

class Data {

    public static function get(){
           global $datav;
           return $datav;
    }

}
```

Comment: Using `global` is discouraged as it relies on a variable being in memory and hold the value you intend it to hold - which can easily be overwritten. You should inject the variable in a constructor if it's needed through the entire class, or a method to set a class property.

Comment: Using a constructor in a static class is not going to be called. He should use a setter, instead.